# Change .docker directory on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

The standard path on Windows where Docker puts stuff is:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\.docker
```

We need to put it here:

```
D:\Docker
```

We couldn't find any info about where or how to change that setting. Any hint appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles upon this question in the future, I added the MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH environment variable as suggested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933107/change-docker-machine-location-windows and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

One solution that works for us is creating a symbolic link:

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\<USER>\.docker" "D:\Docker"
```

But it's not what we call a clean solution.

(All credit for the question & this answer goes to [IMM0rtalis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2414032/imm0rtalis).)

Comment: This will cause `Waiting for SSH to be available...` while run `docker-machine create` - docker for win10 hyper-h mode

Answer (score 0):

You simply can define the environment variable HOME *before* launching a new [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) or [docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) session.

```
set HOME=D:\docker
```

(Add it to your user environment variables if you want it to persists across CMD sessions)

Those tools will look for any config in `$HOME/.xxx`

Comment: Adding `set HOME=D:\Docker` in `start.sh` does not seem to change anything.

Comment: @AndrejStieben In your user environment variable then.