# Change Docker native images location on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: docker, windows-10

*This is not a duplicate of* [Change Docker machine location - Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933107/change-docker-machine-location-windows)

I'm using docker native, version 1.12.1-stable (build: 7135) on Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V enabled.
So docker is **not** running with VirtualBox nor do I have the folder *C:\Users\username\.docker*

I'd like to move docker's images, caches, ... to my secondary drive *D:\*

I guess I should edit the Docker Daemon configuration.

[image: Docker Daemon Configuration]

I tried to add `"graph": "/D/docker"`. Docker started correctly but I couldn't pull any image because of an error

> open /D/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob135686954: no such file or directory

How to tell docker to use another path to store its images, etc ?

Comment: To those, who searching solution working with WSL2, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441307/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-docker-images-when-using-wsl2-with-windows-10-h

Comment: @andrew Youre a savior.

Answer (score 195):

Docker Desktop now can use WSL 2 Backend. In this mode, you need to move the wsl data.

In my case (**Windows10 with Docker Desktop**) none of the above solutions helped me, but I found the solution; run these commands.

This command changes the docker directory to drive `D:` (***don't forget to quit docker desktop first***)

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl --export docker-desktop-data docker-desktop-data.tar
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data
wsl --import docker-desktop-data D:\docker-new-repo\ docker-desktop-data.tar --version 2
```

And now you can delete **.tar** file

There is a very good blog post explaining everything:

https://dev.to/kimcuonthenet/move-docker-desktop-data-distro-out-of-system-drive-4cg2

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Worked for me.  But it needed a few more steps that I got from 
https://dev.to/kimcuonthenet/move-docker-desktop-data-distro-out-of-system-drive-4cg2

Comment: Thanks. it did setup the distro at new location. Howevers the old distro "ext4.vhdx" is still getting updates and size keeps increasing. How can we stop this?

Comment: There are 3 modes of Docker Desktop: Linux container with WSL, Linux container with Hyper-V, and Windows container. This solution works for **Linux container with WSL** where configuration is managed by WSL. [see information from Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#resources)

Comment: For me the last command ends with an error `The specified network name is no longer available.`

Comment: This answer has the most upvotes so is it the recommended way?

Comment: I would like to ask if restoring Docker to default settings will reset the modifications in this answer?

Comment: great! thanks! data in ```C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl``` moved to D: drive, my C: drive is safe

Comment: Also, the same but with more details you can find here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63752264/1151741, helps me on windows move wsl2 to another disk

Comment: Is there a solution for Windows Containers as well?

Answer (score 61):

Docker Version : 2.2.0.3 (42716)

1. Right-click on docker icon on desktop tray

[image]

2. Click on Settings

[image]

3 Click on Resources from the left-hand menu then under the Disk Image location click on browse and change the location

4. Click on apply and restart

Comment: The screen in docker desktop 2.3.0.2 doesn't have these configuration

Comment: well mine still has that option, I updated the docker to 2.3.0.2

Comment: Also thought that the screen is missing, but scrolling down helped. The scrolling pane can be hard to see based on theme used...

Comment: You should disable 'Use the WSL 2 based engine' in Settings -> General to see the ADVANCED options.

Comment: No one here seems to be realizing that Docker Desktop for Windows has two modes: Linux Containers and Windows Containers. (Mode is set in the tray icon context menu.) If you are in Windows containers mode, the disk image location option is not present.

Comment: I am not in Windows containers (as it needs Windows Pro or Enterprise Build to enable it), but my docker doesn't have these configuration too. ps: docker version: 2.5.0.0

Comment: I didn't have the Disk Image Location option so I changed the WSL2 per @DavidJung and restarted Docker Desktop. Now when Docker restarts, it's immediately crashes and prompts to share the crash report. It tries to restart again and crashes again and now in a loop.

Comment: If I change the path to a network drive G:\docker_images, Ducker ist stuck in restart. If I cancel, the old path is shown. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76092428/docker-desktop-does-not-restart-after-changing-path-for-image-location-to-a-netw

Comment: is it just me or this is taking forever ? its been going on for a few hours with no sign of stopping or progress bar or anything...

Comment: In version 4.28.0: In dark mode, the Disk image location in Resources>Advanced settings is not visible. As a workaround, change to light mode.

Answer (score 36):

In 2020 to "Change Docker native images location on Windows 10 Pro" is:

1. quit docker desktop
2. open/edit configuration file `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json`
3. add setting `"data-root": "D:\\Virtual Machines\\Docker"`
4. now start docker desktop
5. run the command `docker info` to see the setting `Docker Root Dir: D:\Virtual Machines\Docker`
6. pull docker images e.g.: `docker pull mongo`
7. you can find the downloaded images in folder `D:\Virtual Machines\Docker\windowsfilter`

Comment: You can place that code to Docker -> Settings -> Docker Engine

Comment: should be 2 "\\" => 
    "data-root": "D:\\VirtualMachines\\Docker"

Comment: should use forward slashes, as in "data-root": "D:/VirtualMachines/Docker"

Answer (score 33):

I found a solution [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-change-image-storage-location-to-other-driver-not-on-c/13592/3)

Docker native, on Windows, runs in a Hyper-V virtual machine.

### Move existing docker VM

I have to move the VM used by docker to the desired location.
I did this using the GUI of *Hyper-V manager*.
The VM for docker is called **MobyLinuxVM**.

- *Right-click* MobyLinuxVM
- Select *Move*
- Select desired location

### Set location of futures Hyper-V VMs

And to be sure futures VMs of Hyper-V will be stored on my secondary drive,
I followed [those instructions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2012/09/11/default-file-locations-in-hyper-v/)

In a powershell terminal (**destination folders must exist**)

`SET-VMHOST –computername <computer> –virtualharddiskpath 'D:\Hyper-V_Virtual-Hard_Disks'`
`SET-VMHOST –computername <computer> –virtualmachinepath 'D:\Hyper-V_VMs'`

Comment: It moves back to the original directory whenever I reboot or restart Docker

Comment: When restarting docker after moving the vm, the hdd location is set back to the default, ending to the creation of a new empty virtual hdd. Obviously, all existing docker stuffs disappears. The workaround for me was to make a symlink in default location pointing the deported one.

Comment: This does not work if docker works with WSL2 support, right?

Answer (score 21):

Edit the Docker Daemon configuration and use `"data-root": "D:\\docker"` instead of `"graph": "/D/docker"`.
That will move all the newly downloaded images to `D:\docker` folder.

> For Old Docker version use graph `"graph": "D:\\docker"`, "graph" has been deprecated.

Comment: Does this work for Docker enterprise on Windows 2019 Servers? Specifically, Docker version 19.03.5, build 2ee0c57608.

Answer (score 16):

There is an easier way to do this: 
Go to **Docker Settings > Advanced > Change "Disk image location"** and click "Apply" when prompted. Docker engine will shut down the VM and **move it for you** to the new location.

**Warning**: new location must not be compressed. If it is then Docker will not show you any error, just won't change location.

Comment: what docker version you use? cause i dont have Advance

Comment: I have been trying this and when I apply the changes, Docker simply sets it back to the location in `c:\Users\Public\Documents` where it wants everything by default

Comment: has no advanced option

Comment: Be careful, and if possible, do a backup. I lost all of my containers and had to revert into factory settings.

Comment: In Docker Community v2.3.x, the click path would be ```Docker > Settings > Resources > Disk Image location``` (you may need to scroll down to see the 'Disk Image Location' option.

Comment: Why I'm not seeing these advance options (I'm running on WSL 2)

Comment: For those with WSL 2 check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66314636/1577343 it worked for me

Comment: "The Advanced tab is only available in Hyper-V mode, because in WSL 2 mode and Windows container mode these resources are managed by Windows. In WSL 2 mode, you can configure limits on the memory, CPU, and swap size allocated to the WSL 2 utility VM." Reason why you are not able to see advance options.

Answer (score 9):

None of these steps worked for me. After reboot or a Docker restart, it would move back to the original path. What worked for me is using [Junction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction)

stop docker engine

create a target folder in the new location:

```
mkdir d:\docker\vhd
```

copy the folder `Virtual Hard Disks` to the target folder

rename (and backup) the original folder

```
rename “C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks” “C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks_backup”
```

create a hard symbolic link (junction)

```
junction.exe "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks" "d:\docker\vhd\Virtual Hard Disks"
```

start docker engine

Answer (score 6):

For Those looking in 2020. The following is for Windows 10 Machine:

1. In the global Actions pane of Hyper-V Manager click Hyper-V
   Settings…
2. Under Virtual Hard Disks change the location from the default to
   your desired location.
3. Under Virtual Machines change the location from the default to your
   desired location, and click apply.

[image]

4. Click OK to close the Hyper-V Settings page.

Answer (score 6):

If issues using the Docker Desktop GUI, when using Hyper-V:

1. Shutdown Docker Desktop
2. Edit `c:\users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json`

   - You need to edit `dataFolder` entry. Use Double backslashes.
   - eg:   `"dataFolder": "D:\\Demo\\Hyper-V\\DockerDesktop\\DockerDesktop"`
3. Restart Docker Desktop

You can also use the above if Docker Desktop loses track of where you data folder is, as the GUI doesn't allow you to set it to a previously used location.

Comment: wsl and daemon.json modification didn't work to me, but hyper-v and this worked.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at Microsoft documentation [**docker engine on windows**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon), it's the `daemon.json` file that allows to change the setting "data-root": "".

Answer (score 2):

**2023 Update:**

Open up docker desktop GUI. On the left sidebar, there's a tab titled Extensions followed by 3 dots/Menu. click it and a toggle menu will appear, click on settings. Click the Resources tab and then click Browse. Update your image location. Here's what you'll see.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699#issuecomment-658369676

He created a [symlink](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/) pointing to the new folder location. By running:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$newLocation = "E:\VMs\WSL2\"

cd "~\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data"
wsl --shutdown
Optimize-VHD .\ext4.vhdx -Mode Full
mkdir $newLocation -Force
mv ext4.vhdx $newLocation
cd ..
rm "data"
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "data" -Target $newLocation
```

He also wrote a blog post going into more detail: http://nuts4.net/post/moving-wsl2-vhdx-file-to-a-different-location

Answer (score -2):

Just configuration from Docker Desktop worked for me (Latest Version V20.10.8)

Steps

1. Go to settings
2. Select 'Docker Engine' option
3. Add property `"data-root": "D:\\Docker"` in configuration file
4. Apply and Restart

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzmFr.png)