# How to install Docker Desktop on a different drive on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I've had Docker Desktop installed on my `C:\` drive for a while now and it keeps hogging space on my SSD. Even if I delete all of my containers and images it still takes a lot of space, I'm guessing some cached files or something. The only way I could recover space on my SSD is to fully uninstall Docker Desktop.

I've been trying to install Docker Desktop onto a larger HDD but it's not an option on the installer. I've seen [some guides](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-could-i-install-docker-for-windows-on-drive-e-my-ssd-c-is-full/52347) about modifying the services and supplying the `--data-root` flag but it doesn't seem to work. I couldn't restart the `dockerd` service, etc.

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-could-i-install-docker-for-windows-on-drive-e-my-ssd-c-is-full/52347

HTH Did not test it yet

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I was also trying to do the same recently; install docker freshly on a different drive. In fact I am trying to keep all my installed application in a separate drive than the Windows os installation.

To install docker on, say, E:\Docker\Docker drive I did the following:

- Don't install using double click on "Docker Desktop Installer.exe".
- Open windows terminal as Administrator.(Right click on the Terminal icon and click on Run as administrator).
- Goto the folder where "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" downloaded. And run `start /w "" "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" install -accept-license  --installation-dir=E:\Docker\Docker`

**One thing it will install docker to separate drive. But the WSL, image etc still will be in %HOME%\AppData\Local\Docker**

Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/#install-from-the-command-line

Comment: This answer is the correct approach. And if you want to also store images in another drive instead of the default location, you need to pass an additional flag `--wsl-default-data-root=E:\Path\to\Data\Folder`.

Comment: Notice: No trailing slashes when providing the paths to installation-dir or default-data-root argument. Also, here's the command to install and also store images to your desired drive:  

`start /w "" "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" install -accept-license  --installation-dir=D:\Docker --wsl-default-data-root=D:\Docker\images`

Comment: I had this error: "Unexpected token 'install' in expression or statement". For solving, I wrote '.\Docker Desktop Installer.exe' and the rest of the commands. Simple quotes and problem solved!

Answer (score 15):

I've tried many methods as suggested and it did install as expected to different drive than C when using command line. The problem was that it worked with linux containers and images but was still saving Windows images and containers in default C ProgramData although I inserted `--windows-containers-default-data-root="D:\Docker"` when installing.

This is what worked for me to install and save images and containers under D drive.

- after download of "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" file
- open the windows terminal as administrator and go to where you downloaded the file
- run the following command

`start /w "" "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" install -accept-license --installation-dir="D:\Docker\Docker" --wsl-default-data-root="D:\Docker\wsl" --windows-containers-default-data-root="D:\\Docker"`

Turns out the flag `--windows-containers-default-data-root="D:\\Docker"` needed two backslashes instead of one.

Comment: Using Windows 11, this saved the day

Comment: works with WSL2 Windows containers on Windows 10 and 11, with version of Docker: 4.27.2. Confirmed C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop only contained some logs. Everything else filled up the D:\containers folder I specified.

Answer (score 6):

- Open PowerShell(Run as Administrator).
- Navigate to that folder where Docker Desktop Installer.exe is located.( `cd folderpath` ).
- Run this command  `Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" -ArgumentList "install -accept-license --installation-dir=E:\Docker"`

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 11 it worked like this:

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" -ArgumentList "install", "-accept-license", "--installation-dir=D:\Docker\Docker", "--wsl-default-data-root=D:\Docker\wsl", "--windows-containers-default-data-root=D:\\Docker"
```

Answer (score 3):

This Worked For me Using CMD(Admin) "D:\UserName\Downloads\Music\Docker Desktop Installer.exe" install -accept-license --installation-dir="E:\Program Files\Docker"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2An8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After installation on a different drive on windows 10, you can face an issue with WSL. An error pops up with information related to wsl and recommends running `wsl --shutdown` command etc. I tried to fix the error but I couldn't.

The only solution I found was to install it again on the main `C:\ drive` but change the image location to a different drive.

Comment: To change location of images being stored: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76941903/8267304

Answer (score 0):

**Windows terminal as administrator** - Start-Process -FilePath "G:\APPS\Docker Desktop Installer.exe" -ArgumentList "install", "-accept-license", "--installation-dir=G:\Docker", "--wsl-default-data-root=G:\Docker\images" -Wait

**Note**: Make sure to create a folder named "Docker" and another folder named "images" inside the Docker folder within your desired volume, in my case it was G:\

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Mujeeb I got the error message suggesting `wsl --shutdown`.
What fixed it for me was creating the specified WSL folder from the original Powershell command.

See https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-installation-directory/32773/24

Answer (score -1):

2Answer Right
u must
First

1. cut the docker desktop installer to a random folder in drive e
   2.create text document on that folder
   and paste this ---->  /w "" "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" install -accept-license  --installation-dir=E:\Docker\Docker
2. Click on Save as and click on all files and write for example hello.bat
   4.now run it

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a blog, forum or chat site. Rather, it is an encyclopaedia-like repository of information. So, please refrain from using vulgar, SMS-oriented abbreviations like "u" and "2answer", and edit your post to use proper English.

Comment: Are you the grammer police?

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this worked well

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" -ArgumentList "install", "-accept-license", "--installation-dir=D:\Docker", "--wsl-default-data-root=D:\Docker\images"
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.