# Docker desktop does not restart after changing path for image location to a network folder

Tags: image, resources, docker-desktop

I use Docker Desktop 4.18.0 on Windows Server 2019 with Hyper-V and
changed the Settings path

Resources => Disk image location

from

C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data

to

G:\docker_images

After clicking "Apply & restart" Docker does not restart correctly but is stuck.
After stopping and starting Docker, the old path is used in the settings.

Using G:\docker_images worked with previous versions of Docker.

=> Is this a bug? If not, how to resolve the issue?

Related:

[Change Docker native images location on Windows 10 Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465979/change-docker-native-images-location-on-windows-10-pro)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a new folder G:\docker and that worked. Don't know why.