# Stop docker from consuming ridiculous amounts of space

Tags: docker

Docker consumes a ridiculous amount of space, which I don't have on my drive.

When I start using it for my project, it just keeps consuming more and more, even if I don't create any new containers or anything. It eventually consumes all the space available and crashes docker and wsl.

I have tried [some other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465979/change-docker-native-images-location-on-windows-10-pro) like trying to change the drive it uses, but it doesn't seem to work. It generates another 10Gb file in %localappdata%/Docker/wsl/data. This doesn't explain why I am running out of space though, as I have ~50Gb free on my main disk.

Even if I try to `docker system prune -a`, is as if the system doesn't recognize it until I restart the computer, and only liberatis ~300Mb (even though the command output says something like 4Gb have been liberated)

Comment: Is the issue with RAM or with hard drive storage?  Prune will clear hard drive space.  Memory usage may actually just be WSL as the Linux kernel by default will use up as much available RAM as possible for it's filecache; the memory is considered usable within WSL but seen as in used  by Windows. Tweaking WSL configuration can help with that.

Comment: This is hard drive storage. I have been eyeing the memory usage, just in case this was some swap space trickery, but it never hits 100% for long