# Windows 10 Home Change Docker Container Installation Path

Tags: windows, docker

**TL;DR:** Can I configure where to install the docker container in windows 10 home?

I installed Docker on WSL2 backend. However I could not find any options to change container installation path. So I tried installing nonetheless,

```
docker pull carlasim/carla:0.8.2
```

installation could not finish because of no space left in C drive. Currently the downloaded data resides in:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data
```

however I could not delete it. After quitting docker desktop I could delete it.

Comment: Refer to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441307/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-docker-images-when-using-docker-desktop-on-wsl2/63752264#63752264

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're talking about images, not containers, and yes, it's entirely possible.

you need to find or create the daemon.json, located at:

- Windows : `C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json`
- Linux : `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

and have it include `"data-root": "folder/path"`

it'll look like this

```
{
 "data-root": "/mnt/path/to/images/folder"
}
```

or

```
{
 "data-root": "E:\path\to\docker\images\folder"
}
```

[Docker daemon docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#configure-the-docker-daemon)

Comment: This works only when using Windows containers in windows 10

Comment: `"data-root": "E:\path\to\docker\images\folder"` did not work for me (Windows Server 2022) - I had to use double-backslashes like `"data-root": "E:\\path\\to\\docker\\images\\folder"` or regular-slashes `"data-root": "E:/path/to/docker/images/folder"`

Comment: For some reason when i include data-root in the daemon.json docker engine fails to start

Comment: Same. Docker completely breaks if `data-root` is there (at least on Windows, and the latest version as of this date)