# Docker change default path for images on Windows

Tags: windows, image, docker, path, default

I'm trying to setup Docker on my PC but with a different path for images. Default is : C:\users<user>\AppData\Local\Docker...
I want the solution that will work with linux container because on windows container i managed to change it.
I mention that I tried:

- to add the graph in daemon.json(after that docker didn't start anymore, it was freezing on STARTING)
- to change from command prompt via wsl command by unregister the service and register back with another path(after the restart, it got stuck again on STARTING..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and trying, I found the solution by exporting as .tar and importing again into another directory path => [How can I change the location of docker images when using Docker Desktop on WSL2 with Windows 10 Home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441307/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-docker-images-when-using-docker-desktop-on-wsl2/63752264#63752264)

Now all images that I download are targeting the new path. Lovely.