# What is stored in the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro\ext4.vhdx file for WSL2?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Docker with WSL2 integration on Windows 10 Home.

While following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441307/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-docker-images-when-using-docker-desktop-on-wsl2) to change the location of the docker images I came across this file:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro\ext4.vhdx`

and couldn't find any explanation online regarding the function of this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run Docker Desktop WSL2 it'll create 2 vm's, one contains volumes, images, etc., and the other is related to the actual Docker Desktop itself, which is the one you're asking about. It's much smaller.

You can see both of them with: `wsl -l -v`

The one you're asking about is for the `docker-desktop` vm.

Comment: The file in `wsl\data` folder has 40GB on my machine and I wonder why. The command above just lists 3 items `Ubuntu-20.04`, `docker-desktop-data`, `docker-desktop`.