# Moving docker image's location to Drive D still occupying drive C's space

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I tried moving `Docker Desktop`'s image's location from System disk to Drive D to avoid over-consuming the system disk

By doing so: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441307/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-docker-images-when-using-docker-desktop-on-wsl2/63752264#:%7E:text=The%20WSL%202,your%20command%20prompt%3A)

```
1. Export docker-desktop-data into a file:
    - wsl --export docker-desktop-data "D:\Docker\wsl\data\docker-desktop-data.tar"

2. Unregister docker-desktop-data from wsl:
    - wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data

3. Import the docker-desktop-data back to wsl, but now the ext4.vhdx would reside in different drive/directory:
    - wsl --import docker-desktop-data "D:\Docker\wsl\data" "D:\Docker\wsl\data\docker-desktop-data.tar" --version 2

Start the docker again, and also reboot to make sure everything works fine.
```

Now, in my wsl2 ubuntu distro, I tried importing sql dumps into the db container in docker.

I can see that both drive C and D 's space is getting reduced as the import goes on.

But mostly, drive C gets reduced more than drive D.

**Note:** I also moved the WSL2 instance in drive D, [reference](https://www.msftnext.com/how-to-move-the-wsl-linux-subsystem-to-another-disk-or-partition/#:%7E:text=Method%202,save%20your%20time.)

Is this normal that drive C still gets consumed even after moving the docker's image location and WSL2 instance to Drive D?

If it isn't, can someone point out where I did wrong and how to resolve?

BTW, when I run `wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04`, I can see in terminal that it's prefixed with `username@DESKTOP-######:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32`, is this also normal even after moving the wsl2 instance to drive D?