# Setting up TensorFlow

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I have installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 laptop. I started Docker quickstart and in the shell prompt ran

```
 docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

This downloads all the necessary files and I see

```
[I 10:54:41.612 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to   /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
  [W 10:54:41.633 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP    addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
 [W 10:54:41.633 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.
 [I 10:54:41.642 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /notebooks
 [I 10:54:41.643 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
   [I 10:54:41.643 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
  [I 10:54:41.644 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

I tried http://127.0.0.1:8888 on my laptop but I think I need to do this from the Docker container. But I don't know how to start the browser within Docker to be able to access the notebooks.

Can you let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect answer in another stackoverflow post [How to setup learning environment for Udacity Deep Learning class with TensorFlow (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601882/how-to-setup-learning-environment-for-udacity-deep-learning-class-with-tensorflo/40449081#40449081)

Ignore the question.

Thanks
Ganesh